# Chrome extension executescript into external drive file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I have created an extension that uses the `executescript` api to inject a piece of code (shown below) that basically on `window.onbeforeunload` confirms they want to close the page. I have the script working, and by using the `file://*/*` permission, got it to inject on file URLs. However, when testing it on a flash game I downloaded, the script didn't inject. The URL was `externalfile:drive-randomtext/root/SWFNAME.swf`. I tried adding  `externalfile://*/*` in the permissions but got the following error message: `There were warnings when trying to install this extension: Permission 'externalfile://*/*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.` Is there an external file permission, or another way to do this?

Manifest.json:

```
{

  "name": "name",
  "short_name": "name",
  "version": "3.6",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Desc",
  "permissions": [
     "storage",
     "http://*/",
     "https://*/",
     "tabs",
     "activeTab",
     "webNavigation",
     "*://*/*",
     "file://*/*"
  ],
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png"
  },
  "background": {
     "scripts": ["disabled.js"]
  }

}
```

Script that gets executed:

(hotkey-binding code too long, can be found [here](https://craig.is/killing/mice))

```
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+m', function(e) {
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;function confirmExit(){alert('confirm exit is being called');return'Close page?';}
alert('Enabled');
    return false;
});

Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+q', function(e) {
location.reload();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you check the file access box at chrome://extensions ?

Comment: so you want to inject jsvascript into a flash file?

Comment: into the tab that is running the file, yes.